# change venv from python 3.5 to python 3.6; Gunicorn does not start

Tags: python-3.x, django, gunicorn

My app on python3.5 works well. But when I make the virtualenv with python3.6 and install the same requirements; Gunicorn doesn't start with below error message in jenkins:

```
+ supervisorctl restart myapp
myapp: stopped
myapp: ERROR (spawn error)
```

and in log file it's written:

```
supervisor: couldn't exec /home/jenkins/myapp/venv/bin/gunicorn: ENOENT
supervisor: child process was not spawned
```

Also, the gunicorn package version is 19.8.1. I updated it to 20.0.0 but it doesn't work

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is relevant to mismatch versions of jenkins and python 3.6.

Comment: Jenkins?  What does that have to do with it?   It might be a Jenkins >>plugin<< version. I guess.